# sprintf() produces different string when unicode character (specifically, é) is used

Tags: r, printf, string-formatting, unicode-string

Why does `sprintf("%-10s: 1.4f\n", "Renyi", 0)` and `sprintf("%-10s: 1.4f\n", "Rényi", 0)` not give the same string (R version 3.4.2)? The latter is one character shorter, removing a space before `:`.

The latter version is what I actually want to print; how can I print it without this formatting difference?